# How to vertically and horizontally align an image in a DIV without altering width/height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, alignment

Is there any way? Using Javascript/JQuery? I really really really need it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use JavaScript when you aren't required to....

### Background method

You could set it as the background...

```
div {
   background: url(/path/to/img.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/J2HHe/).

---

### `position: absolute` method

Or you could position the `img` absolutely...

```
div {
   position: relative;
}

div img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -50px;
   margin-top: -50px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/X4Xnw/).

Where `-50px` is half the respected dimension of the image.

---

### `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` method

You could also use `vertical-align: middle`.

```
div {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Vt5ed/).

Keep in mind this won't work < IE8.

<sup>There are even more ways to achieve this too...</sup>

Comment: Go to my page roseannebarr.tumblr.com and look at the images. (Press next & previous to go to each DIV) There will be multiple images in different DIVs, the images will all be different heights and different widths.

Comment: @Earl In that case, use the 1st or 3rd example above.